# Having issues setting up a host volume with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a little test/intro project for Docker and Elixir. I want to have it so that the src folder in my project's directory is accessible to both the host and the container.

Docker Compose File

```
version: "3"

services:
  webapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./webapp.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80
    #depends_on:
      #- db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project
    environment:
      - DEPLOYMENT=development

#   db:
#     image: postgres:13.1-alpine
#     volumes:
#       - db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

# volumes:
#   db-volume:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM elixir:1.13-alpine

WORKDIR /srv/project

RUN pwd

RUN ls -la

RUN elixir test.exs
```

I've added pwd and ls -la just for debugging. They show that I'm in the correct directory and that there are no files here. I was able to COPY the file in and things worked but obviously that's not what I'm looking for. I tried deleting the src folder and running it and the src folder came back. I tried RUN touch test.txt and the file showed up in the container but not on the host.

What am I messing up here? Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker build is run first, then the resulting image is instanciated by docker-compose, you will never see the files that are shared from the docker-compose bind mount in the docker build (they are not used during the build step), if there are no COPYs in the Dockerfile, the RUN ls -la will always show nothing.

Comment: So, when does it become available? I just tried removing all the RUN commands and adding "CMD ls -la" instead, then after building it, I ran an instance of the image, and still see now file. I tried "CMD elixir test.exs" and got "no file named test.exs" Is there another issue with my code?

Comment: Finally figured it out thanks to your comment and then after work today I realized I probably had to use docker-compose up after the build instead docker run, due to the volume being described via the compose file instead of the dockerfile.

It works now, thanks!